# Not sure how to design in app notifications from interactions (likes, share, etc...)

Tags: android, firebase, websocket, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am developing an Android application in Kotlin that can be thought of as similar to Instagram.

I am designing how to implement my in-app notifications. By "in-app notifications" I mean **interactions** such as likes, publication sharing, new chat message, etc.

For the moment, I do want foreground notifications. The notifications would not involve any view component.

The proposed flow would be:

1. Interaction action from Client_1 (like, share, message) triggers an Event_A in the server.
2. Event_A produces a state change and generates a notification to Client_2.
3. Client_2 receives the notification
   a. Display a badge in the notification icon bar.
   b. Generates a new item in the notifications list when Client_2 open it.

> I make this clarification because, while searching this, I've seen "in-app notifications" are related to campaigns, publicity, new features, etc.

So far, I though two possible implementations but not sure if they are the right ones.

**1 - Web Sockets**
My app already uses Web Sockets for handling chat messages. However, so far, the connection is only open when the user enters to the chat view.

I consider easy to implement but this implies having an open connection the entire time the user is on the app and may be an unnecessary load for the server and an increment on Web Socket's time session.

**2 - SNS + FCM**
I've found that AWS SNS and FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) is a common approach for handling notifications.

However, reading the Firebase's documentation and examples, I understand it's mostly used for the other kind of in-apps notifications (campaigns, publicity, new features, etc).

> In this [FCM's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), it defines two types of messages: `Notification Messages` and `Data Messages`. I understand, `Data Messages` would be more appropiate for my use case.

Don't know it is worth the complexity of configuring FCM and handling the token's lifecycle.

**So, my questions are**:

- Are the above scenarios good approaches? Is there any other way to achieve this?
- Which is the correct term for this kind of notifications?

Answer (score 0):

FCM is just normal push messaging.  It can be used for any type of data.  It's just a general method for a server to push data to an app, even if the app isn't running at the moment.  So it's the right answer.  The problem with web sockets is it won't work if your app is shut down either by the user or by the system.